# Which Game of Thrones LCG house/expansions best reflect a play style similar to 'blue' decks in MTG?

Tags: game-of-thrones-card-game

I've recently committed to buying the Game of Thrones Living Card Game from Fantasy Flight so I can play with a number of friends who also have it.

At this stage, I know will be buying the Core set, but am a bit overwhelmed at all the available expansions and chapter packs. To be competitive amongst my friends (not tournaments), I know I need to get additional cards beyond those in the core set.

I really enjoyed playing 'blue' decks in Magic due to their control of the field and 'tricks' up their sleeve by being able to cancel or negate the effects of my opponents.  I really dislike rush/monster heavy decks as well.

**So, my question is, which Game of Thrones LCG house/expansions best reflect a play style similar to 'blue' decks in MTG as described above?**

Comment: I will reword the question so it is not a recommendation

Comment: The Lannisters. As for expansions, I'm uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've been playing the game now for almost a year. Have gotten to the finals in a store championship and won some private tournaments amongst my meta (about 6-8 players) :)

To answer my own question,  it would be the lannisters due to the sheer amount of kneeling effects that they have. Martell would be a close second in terms of annoying events and the general 'negative play experience' it gives to your opponents via icon stripping and challenge denial